# should we use a dash "-" between words of an adjective when omit a noun?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary, adjective-phrases

I know the question may seem too vague and weird, so let's go right to the example for more clarification:

> Scholars ask the-upper-class countries to help **the-lower-class** in the breakout of the coronavirus.

As you see, I omitted countries after " **the-lower-class**" so as to be more concise. Now, did I use  **"the lower class"**, would it be wrong or it is actually more correct?
Furthermore, I'm not sure whether I can use the-lower-class or its counterparts for countries; therefore, please feel free to rectify it as well, but please don't overlook my main question, which is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a *hyphen* after *the*, just between the two halves of the compound adjective. It makes no difference whether you omit the following noun or not.

However, as you suspect, *lower-class* is not an appropriate way to describe a nation. Even when I was at school 50+ years ago, the term *underdeveloped countries* was being replaced by *developing countries*, as it was regarded as insulting.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developing_country